# what does "has a realization" mean?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider the following problem:

> Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is an $L$-structure and $A \subseteq M$ is non-empty. Prove that if every $L_A$-formula in one free variable that has a realisation in $\mathcal{M}$ actually has a realisation in $A$, then $A$ is the universe of an elementary substructure of $\mathcal{M}$.

What does "has a realisation" mean in this context?

Comment: It means that there is at least one object that will satisfy the formula.

Comment: @Bram28, do you mean: "Let $\phi(v)$ be an $L_A$-formula in one free variable. If there is some $m \in M$ such that $\mathcal{M }\models \phi(m)$, then there will be some $a \in A$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models \phi(a)$."?

Comment: basically yes ... but you have to be careful ... objects from the domain are not the same as constants from yourlanguage

Comment: @bbw: if there is an $a \in M$ with $M \vDash \phi(a)$ then there is an $a \in A$ with $A \vDash \phi(a)$.  The second satisfaction relation is for $A$.

Comment: @CarlMummert but $A$ is just a subset not a structure yet, how do you define the satisfication?

Comment: @bbw: I would define it in the normal way.  There's a lack of context in the problem - what book did it come from? I assume $L$ has no function symbols, so that every subset of a structure is a substructure.